# How to deal without goto in Bash?

Tags: command-line, bash

Bash doesn't have a goto operator. I have a simple task, and I can't figure out how to solve it without goto or adding a new proc, and that is undesireable.

I have two conditions and a block of code that should work this way:

[ condition 1 ] if true run some commands and check [ condidion 2 ]; if false exec a block of code.

[ condition 2 ] if true don't exec the same block of code; if false do execute the same block.

Is it solvable, or I have to define some proc and use `exit` there? I used a flag var, but I don't like it.

With goto available it would look this way:

```
[ cond 1 ] || goto label 1
  command
  ...
  command
  [ cond 2 ] && goto label 2

:label 1

block of code

:label 2
```

Something like that.

Comment: Old Unix's Thompson shell actually [used to have `goto` statement in the past](https://askubuntu.com/a/1042780/295286). That's besides the point, however. How would you express what you want in pseudocode with `goto` ?  Perhaps functions would be appropriate here.

Comment: Hold on, I will write it with goto.

Comment: I've rewritten my answer a bit. Let me know if anything doesn't make sense or needs extra clarification.

Comment: I first learned of GOTO in old BASIC classes a few decades ago. Now even modern BASIC languages frown against it's use. Recently I've seen it in grub code which is pretty ugly IMO. With good program design I really don't see a need for GOTO's. In Assembly language it's very prevalent, "Branch" instruction either conditionally on test or unconditionally (GOTO): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_(computer_science)

Comment: By "new proc" I assume you mean start a new script?

Comment: Damn!  I missed this question!  You should have pinged me in chat!  **;-)**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The typical way to work to use branching in shell scripts would be via functions declared before main block of code. However, I think the underlying issue here is the logical one, and not the goto.  Obviously `label 1` is repeated, so this can live as function. But also, condition 2 could be turned into a function that also calls `label 1` for the sake of readability:

```
#!/bin/bash

label1(){
    echo "label 1 function"
}

check_cond2(){
    if ! [ condition2 ]; then
        label1 arg1 arg2
    fi
}

if [ condition1  ]; then

    command
    ...
    command
    check_cond2
else 
    label1
fi

othercommand2
othercommand3
```

What I've noticed is that in both conditions you have `if false exec a block of code` and `if false exec a block of code`, so one idea would be to start at checking whether those conditions both false. However, making something like `if ! [ cond1 ] || ! [ cond2 ]` would change branching logic. You can still see the pseudocode version of that by seeing this posts edit history.

Comment: The problem is that I am afraid upstream won't accept new procs in that script. One function will be enough.

Comment: @Pilot6 I think the upstream may be misunderstanding what a process is and isn't. Functions in bash run in current shell, no new process: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/305360/85039  But any non-builtin command is a process, regardless of whether it runs in function or not

Answer (score 12):

When I moved from Windows to Linux on my desktop, I had a lot of pre-existing `.BAT` and `.CMD` files to convert and I wasn't going to rewrite the logic for them, so I [found](https://bobcopeland.com/blog/2012/10/goto-in-bash/) a way to do a `goto` in bash that works because the `goto function` runs `sed` on itself to strip out any parts of the script that shouldn’t run, and then evals it all.

*The below source is slightly modified from the original to make it more robust*:

```
#!/bin/bash

# BAT / CMD goto function
function goto
{
    label=$1
    cmd=$(sed -n "/^:[[:blank:]][[:blank:]]*${label}/{:a;n;p;ba};" $0 | 
          grep -v ':$')
    eval "$cmd"
    exit
}

apt update

# Just for the heck of it: how to create a variable where to jump to:
start=${1:-"start"}
goto "$start"

: start
goto_msg="Starting..."
echo $goto_msg
# Just jump to the label:
goto "continue"

: skipped
goto_msg="This is skipped!"
echo "$goto_msg"

: continue
goto_msg="Ended..."
echo "$goto_msg"

# following doesn't jump to apt update whereas original does
goto update
```

and I do not feel guilty at all as Linus Torvalds famously said:

> From: Linus Torvalds
> Subject: Re: any chance of 2.6.0-test*?
> Date:  Sun, 12 Jan 2003 11:38:35 -0800 (PST)
>
> I think goto's are fine, and they are often more readable than large amounts of indentation. That's *especially* true if the code flow isn't actually naturally indented (in this case it is, so I don't think using goto is in any way *clearer* than not, but in general goto's can be quite good for readability).
>
> Of course, in stupid languages like Pascal, where labels cannot be descriptive, goto's can be bad. But that's not the fault of the goto, that's the braindamage of the language designer.

[Original source for the code](https://bobcopeland.com/blog/2012/10/goto-in-bash/)  (modified to make it less error prone)
[The source for the quote](http://koblents.com/Ches/Links/Month-Mar-2013/20-Using-Goto-in-Linux-Kernel-Code/)

Comment: "that's not the fault of the goto, that's the braindamage of the language designer" Linus being a polite gentleman, as always.

Comment: If he feels that way about `goto` then why did he not push to implement any in `bash`?

Comment: Perhaps because Linus is not the author of `bash` (Stephen Bourne is). :-)

Answer (score 11):

You should put your `block_of_code` into a function and use some if/else:

```
my_function() {
    block of code
    ...
}

if [[ condition 1 ]] ; then
    command
    ...
    command

    if [[ ! condition 2 ]] ; then
        # label 1
        my_function
    fi

else
    # label 1
    my_function
fi

# label 2
```