# How to loop a simple batch file utilizing ECHO?

Tags: bash, scripts

I am attempting to achieve the effect of a batch file that does something similar to the following concept:

```
:start
ECHO 1
ECHO 2
ECHO 3
ECHO 4
ECHO 5
goto start
```

That is how I would make a batch file in Windows, but I am new to Linux, and would like to achieve a similar idea here in this operating system.

Comment: `while true ; do echo 1 ; echo 2 ; echo 3 ; echo 4 ; echo 5 ; done`

Comment: goto is very bad programming practice. Learn about the control loops in bash.

Comment: Somewhat related: [How to deal without goto in Bash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058498/how-to-deal-without-goto-in-bash)

Answer (score 3):

In bash scripting you do not have *goto*s; you should use a `while` loop. For the `while` loop to run endlessly, you can use the `true` command which returns status of `0` (meaning successful run of a command).

So, you can create your "endless" loop like this:

```
while true ; do
  echo 1
  echo 2
  echo 3
  echo 4
  echo 5
done
```